# Type Error : contract " erc20interface " should be marked as abstract

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethcore

Code :

```
contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Disregard what the previous poster, OWADVL, said. This is a place for both learning and to get past difficulties found while coding. Answers like his push people away who are simply here trying to expand their knowledge. OWADVL is correct, though, in saying that you are using an older version of Solidity. Unless you are specifically using deprecated functions only supported in older versions, using the newest version is usually recommended. However, he is wrong again in pointing out your preference of operating systems. Remix IDE is entirely a browser based IDE, so it truly does not matter which OS you use as ultimately it will be running in a browser instance.

With that said, you can fix that entire block of errors by changing:

- Line 45: "contract ERC20Interface" to "interface IERC20"
- You may also want to change the "public" keyword used in each function to "external" for the functions in the interface only
- To change the version of Solidity, use "pragma solidity >=0.8.4 <0.9.0;" at the very top of your code (There are a few newer versions, but this is currently the accepted stable version)

The idea here being that you are using the Interface for ERC20 and later inheriting this Interface and it's functions for your own contract.

Here are 2 *FREE* resources that may help you further your knowledge:

- https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/solidity/develop/solidity.pdf
- https://docs.appery.io/docs/eth-app-example-part1

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple things wrong with what you do.

1. it's not a good idea to screenshot everything
2. it's not a good idea to use windows for crypto development
3. you're using an old version of solidity
4. you should start with the basics before venturing to tokens.

get a book, [https://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Ethereum-Building-Smart-Contracts/dp/1491971940](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491971940) ... read it.

We all try to cut corners but this isn't working with smart contracts :)

Answer (score 0):

***Can be solve by writing the code as below:***

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

interface IERC20 {
    
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) external view returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) external view returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens); }
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of the error? and how does your answer fixes it?